# How do I import a VMWare image into VirtualBox 4.0x?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import VMWare Workstation 7 VM into Sun VirtualBox (latest version)?](https://superuser.com/questions/86042/how-to-import-vmware-workstation-7-vm-into-sun-virtualbox-latest-version)

How do I import a VMWare 3.0x  image into VirtualBox 4.0x ?   VirtualBox no longer has the "Add" option in the Virtual Disk Manager .