# Virtualbox headless: How to join and convert segmented vmware images into vbox?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I got VMware image in 4 files:

- image.vmdk
- image-s001.vmdk
- image-s002.vmdk
- image-s003.vmdk

The 1st (image.vmdk) is only an small XML file, and the actual images are in the 3 segments.

I want run the image in the Virtualbox HEADLESS - so, i havn't access to Virtualbox GUI.

AFAIK, the Virtualbox can use/convert VMware images, but not the segmented images, or, something i'm doing wrong.

Question:

How to convert (or use) those segmented .vmdk files into Virtualbox? (i'm using using virtualbox-ose-4.1.14)

I was already:

- read [How to import VMware Workstation 7 VM into Sun VirtualBox (latest version)?](https://superuser.com/questions/86042/how-to-import-vmware-workstation-7-vm-into-sun-virtualbox-latest-version), (and several others) but the questions and answers are **NOT** for *segmented* images, nor for *headless* operation.
- somewhere found a mention about the command vmware-vdiskmanager - but i'm not sure than it will works.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you try if the [`VBoxManage clonehd`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi) command can copy the segmented files into a new file.

Comment: nope: i got error: "VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium"... maybe doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware Converter can combine the disk images into one file.  It can also convert to OVF and other VM formats.

You'll need to do this on a regular workstation, then move the file over to your VirtualBox host.

Comment: for trying this, need a copy of VMware? or the tool is included into some trial version?

Comment: The standalone converter is a free tool - https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter

Comment: Dead link. I googled for the name but the listings don't seem to do what is required.

Answer (score 1):

With Virtualbox GUI, you just have to choose the 1st image.vmdk as disk for your virtual machine.

Comment: as i told above - running headless - so havent gui...